# How do you create a Reports diagram in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect, documentation-generation, data-dictionary

I am trying to create a Reports diagram with a model document and report specification in Enterprise Architect.  The embarrassing part of this is that I've done this before, but can't work out how I did it.  And I didn't take notes which I probably should do since this is something like a once every 2 years task for me.

In an older EA project, I have model document w/ custom templates in a reports diagram that will generate a data dictionary.  Works great and I want that same thing for an EA project for a different, unrelated project.

But I can seem to figure out the first step, which is that Reports Diagram.

I am using version EA 13.0.1307.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the required MDG technology active.
   You need the **Core Extentions** MDG to be able to create documentation diagrams
2. Create a **Documentation Diagram**
   When creating a new diagram select **Extented** from the left pane, and **Documentation** from the right pane

Now the toolbox should show the elements you need to create your virtual document.

Comment: Thanks!  I eventually found it.  But I'll probably forget it again in 2 years and then I'll find this answer. Thanks in advance!